# Apache Commons FTPClient Not Retrieving All Bytes From Source File

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I have a fairly basic [3.8.0 FTPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) use case:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient()

ftpClient.connect(hostName, hostPort)

if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpClient.getReplyCode())) {
  ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)
  ftpClient.login(userName, password)

  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("localFile.txt")

  ftpClient.retrieve("remoteFile.zip", fos)
}
```

The problem I have is that the resulting local file is always ~1400 Bytes smaller than the remote source file:

```
source file size: 134,914,722
dest file size:   134,913,316
```

This doesn't seem to be a server problem since the standard linux ftp command retrieves the  entire file.

It also doesn't seem to be `OutputStream` related because I have the same problem when I pull the file contents into memory:

```
//still too small
Byte[] fileContents = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("remoteFile.zip").readAllBytes()
```

**What would cause the apache commons FTPClient to allow connectivity and file download but not exhaustively retrieve all bytes from the source file?**

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the ordering of `setFileType`; it should have come after `login` instead of before.

```
ftpClient.connect(...

ftpClient.login(...

ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)
```

The file coming in smaller was likely due to charset interpretations of the raw zip file.

Comment: Indeed, you need to select the mode after login. ASCII mode basically interprets the receiving end system and the then converts the line endings based on what receiving end prefers(LF/CRLF/CR). Thus using ASCII mode eg. with ZIP files will likely cause corrupted file. BINARY mode transfers without any modifications to content.

Comment: You may also change to mode at any point after login, eg. upload 'test.txt' as ASCII and then 'mydoc.pdf' as BINARY within same session.